# Binding parameters for SELECT in CDBCriteria

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I'm using Yii CDBCriteria to find records.

I have to put a string value as a custom column in "SELECT" like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array('*, DATE_ADD(createdon, INTERVAL :timezonediff SECOND) as createdon' );       
$criteria->condition = "some_amount > 1000";        
$criteria->params = array(':timezonediff' => "10800");      
$transModel = new TransactionModel;
```

I'm having a problem where I'm not able to provide the value for ":timezonediff" token in SELECT.

`$criteria->params` is only working for the tokens in condition but not for SELECT.

I even tried to give an array in `$criteria->select`, but it didn't work.

Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong here ?

Comment: what is in $main_condition?

Comment: @Robm It's got some other conditions.

Comment: @robm i think its creating some confusion, let me edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for contributing. I have solved the issue. I was doing a mistake which was causing an error. I was providing this criteria to another object which did not have :timezonediff token.

Parameters for the tokens even in "select" can be binded in $criteria->params smoothly and it will create no error. So technically there will be no error in the code I posted in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get around this through a [`CDbExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression):

```
$criteria->select=array(
    '*',
    new CDbExpression('DATE_ADD(`createdon`, INTERVAL :timezonediff SECOND) as createdon',array(
        ':timezonediff'=>10800,
    )),
);
```

Comment: I posted my own answer as I was doing some mistake. Your solution makes sense, but I tried it and it was not binding the token.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try :-|

Comment: I saw some posts after your reply, almost everyone has recommended the same thing as you did but I'm not sure why I'm unable to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$criteria->condition = $main_condition;     
$criteria->params = array(':timezonediff'=>$main_condition);
```